# How to return a list of objects using a Django REST API post request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to using REST API's and am trying to create an API where I can make a POST request containing keywords, which should then return a list of articles related to that keyword.

The reason I can't use a GET request is because I am not GETting anything from a database, I am creating the list of articles based on the keyword from the POST request.

Views.py:

```
def article_get(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = serializers.ArticleListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

classes.py:

```
class Article:
    
    title = ""
        url = ""

    def __init__(self, url, title):
                self.title = title
        self.url = url
class ArticleList:
    keywords = ""
    articles = []

    def __init__(self, keywords, articles):
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.articles = articles
                
                self.articles.append(serializedArticle)
```

The `self.articles.append(serializedArticle)` line appends a serialized article to the articles list,
which I hoped would simply add an article in JSON format to the articlelist, but instead it produces the following error:
`Object of type ArticleSerializer is not JSON serializable`

```
serializers.py:
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=300)
    url = serializers.CharField(max_length=300)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return classes.Article(**validated_data)

class ArticleListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    articles = serializers.ListField()
    keywords = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return classes.ArticleList(**validated_data)
```

As I mentioned, I am FAR from being an API expert. I had hoped that by appending a serialized Article object to the ArticleList, that it would be able to return the ArticleList in the response, but it can't.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or: does anyone know if I'm even on the right track? I'm struggling to understand the django REST API documentation so I reckon there's a big chance I'm making some dumb mistakes. So: any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A more "RESTful" approach, for some value of "REST", is to include those tokens in the query params of a GET request like `http://example.com/Article?search_tokens=foo,bar,baz,42`  .  Then you override [`get_filterqueryset`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering)  See also [`django-filter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve or filter data you need to store it somewhere. Not necessarily a database. It can be in memory, for instance:

database.py

```py
database = {
    "articles": 
    [
        {
            "title": "Prepopulated Article",
            "url": "http://prepropulated.example.com",
            "keywords": ["prepopulated", "stuff"]
        }
    ],
}
```

serializers.py

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    url = serializers.URLField()
    keywords = serializers.ListField()
```

views.py

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from myapp.api.serializers import ArticleSerializer
from myapp.database import database

@api_view(['POST'])
def article_create(request): 
    """ Endpoint for creating articles """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            database['articles'].append(serializer.data)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def article_list(request): 
    """ Endpoint for listing Articles """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = []
        keywords = request.data.pop('keywords', None)

        # Would be equivalent to filtering a QuerySet
        if keywords and isinstance(keywords, list):
            for key in keywords:
                for obj in database['articles']:
                    if key in obj['keywords'] and obj not in data:
                        data.append(obj)

        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        print(database['articles'])
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=database['articles'], many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If we send the following payload to create endpoint:

```
{
    "title": "Article One",
    "url": "http://article-one.example.com",
    "keywords": ["new", "stuff"]
}
```

And this payload to `list` endpoint. Then it returns the new created article:

```
{
    "keywords": ["new"]
}
```

Whereas the one below would return both articles.

```
{
    "keywords": ["stuff"]
}
```

A few notes:

1. Using `keywords` as a list to improve the filtering (instead of string).
2. The pseudo-database will reset every time you reload the server. So objects you create using the endpoint will be deleted.

Comment: Awesome, this comment got me on the right track. Using the in memory stored database fixed my problems! Thanks a lot.